# How should I be Mocking this simple Service layer method?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have the following simple method, in my Service layer. I'm not sure how I should mock out the different chained parts, starting from the repository?

```
public ICollection<GameFile> FindAllActiveGamesFiles()
{
    return _gameFileRepository // <- this is an IRepository<GameFile>
        .Find() // <-- returns an IQueryable<T> .. in this case, an IQueryable<GameFile>
        .WhereIsActive() // <-- a simple Pipe/Filter; 'where x.IsActive'
        .ToList();
}
```

My preference is to use Moq, but I'm very happy to see other implimentations .. mainly because i'm not after the exact syntax answer, but the theortical answer. Ie. U need to mock the `IRepository<GameFile>` and setup the `ToList()` method only .. blah blah blah...

That's the stuff I don't get what I should be mocking.

Cheers :)

### --- Update : to clarify my question

What i'm trying to test is that the method 'FindAllActiveGamesFiles()' works. As such, I believe I need to mock the gameFileRepository (which is an interface). I'm not sure if this is the ONLY thing i should be mocking in this example.

eg.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    // Arrange.
    Mock<IRepository<GameFile>> mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<GameFile>>();
    mockRepository.Setup(....).MoreStuffToDo(...); // <-- that's what i'm unsure about.
    IGameFileService = new GameFileService(mockRepository, fakeLoggingService);

    // Act.
    var gameFiles = gameFileService.FindAllActiveGamesFiles();

    // Asserts.
    Assert.IsNotNull(gameFiles);
    CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreNotNull(gameFiles.ToArray());
    // .. and more asserts ///
    // What about expectations? eg. that ToList() was entered/called?
}
```

Comment: I am confused! You do not mock the method, you mock the type/interface. So do you mean how to set expectations for unit test?

Comment: It sounds like you want to unit test this method by mocking the various calls. My take is that the above example is far too simple to test. If your test code ends up being more complicated than the code under test, you're wasting your time. Spend it visually validating the method and move on.

Comment: If you have similar, more complicated chained methods to mock, you basically need to create a mock for each returned object with a single expectation (if each method in the chain returns a different object as you have here). It can be a real PITA to setup and validate, so it only pays off if the parameters passed to the individual method calls are complex and require testing. Don't waste your time testing that the `userName` parameter was passed to `byUserName()`.

Comment: @David Harkness & @Aliostad - i've updated the OP to further explain my question. I understand that the above scenario is possibly contrite, but it's still a real world example AND I feel that I still need to test this method.

Comment: What exactly are you testing inside of FindAllActiveGamesFiles() ?  It's just calling _gameFileRepository.Find().WhereIsActive().ToList();  Are you already testing each of these methods?  If so, then you're done. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to write a test that demonstrates coverage of your Linq statement.  You've already pointed out that your repository is a interface (IRepository<GameFile>) and should be mocked.  You just need some examples of how to demonstrate that your service layer filters the contents of the repository correctly.

Here's your ServiceLayer as I understand it.

```
public class ServiceLayer
{
     private readonly IRepository<GameFile> _gameRepository;

     public SerivceLayer(IRepository<GameFile> repository)
     {
         _gameRepository = repository;
     }

     public IEnumerable<GameFile> FindAllActiveGamesFiles()
     {
         return _gameRepository
                    .Find()  // method we need to mock
                    .Where( gameFile => gameFile.IsActive)
                    .ToList();
     }
}
```

Let's write some tests....  (NUnit and Moq)

```
[TestFixture]
public class ServiceLayerFixture
{
      protected IRepository<GameFile> Repository;
      protected ServiceLayer Subject;
      protected ICollection<GameFile> Results;

      [Setup]
      public void Setup()
      {
          // create our mock
          Repository = new Mock<IRepository<GameFile>>().Object;

          // initialize our test subject
          Subject = new ServiceLayer(Repository);
      }

      [Test]
      public void WhenRepositoryDoesNotContainItems_ServiceLayer_ReturnsAnEmptyCollection()
      {
         Mock.Get(Repository)
             .Setup( r => r.Find())
             .Returns( new List<GameFile>().AsQueryable() );

         Results = Subject.FindAllActiveGameFiles();

         Assert.AreEqual(0, Results.Count);
      }

      [Test]
      public void WhenRepositoryDoesNotContainActiveItems_ServiceLayer_ReturnsAnEmptyCollection()
      {
         Mock.Get(Repository)
             .Setup( r => r.Find())
             .Returns( 
                 new List<GameFile>()
                     {
                        new GameFile { IsActive = false },
                        new GameFile { IsActive = false }
                     }.AsQueryable() );

         Results = Subject.FindAllActiveGameFiles();

         Assert.AreEqual(0, Results.Count);            
      }

      [Test]
      public void WhenRepositoryContainActiveItems_ServiceLayer_FiltersItemsAppropriately()
      {
         Mock.Get(Repository)
             .Setup( r => r.Find())
             .Returns( 
                 new List<GameFile>()
                     {
                        new GameFile { IsActive = true },
                        new GameFile { IsActive = false }
                     }.AsQueryable() );

         Results = Subject.FindAllActiveGameFiles();

         Assert.AreEqual(1, Results.Count);            
      }
}
```

Where your code stops short is that you could be handling exceptions from your IRepository more gracefully.

So consider:

```
[Test]
public void WhenTheRepositoryFails_ServiceLayer_ShouldHandleExceptionsGracefully()
{
    Mock.Get(Repository)
        .Setup( r => r.Find())
        .Throws( new InvalidOperationException() );

    Results = Subject.FindAllActiveGameFiles();

    Assert.AreEqual(0, Results.Count);          
}
```

Or, maybe you want to wrap the exception?

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(GameFileNotFoundException))]
public void WhenTheRepositoryFails_ServiceLayer_ShouldReportCustomError()
{
    Mock.Get(Repository)
        .Setup( r => r.Find())
        .Throws( new InvalidOperationException() );

    Subject.FindAllActiveGameFiles();
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. This is an excellent answer with various in depth examples. I wish I could give u more points. Well done and thanks, mate!

Comment: Is there no way to test `WhereIsActive()` in isolation? As you add more query methods (`FindAllActiveGameFilesOlderThan(date)`, `FindAllActiveGameFilesOwnedBy(user)`, etc), the number of test methods with duplicate code will grow considerably, and you'll be testing the same code path multiple times.

Comment: I merely simplified the example to illustrate it's the Find method that needs to be mocked.  Once you have a IQueryable<T>, the extension methods will simply work.  Functional goodness FTW!

Answer (score 0):

By asserting things about the value returned from `ToList()`, it appears that you are trying to test the actual methods `Find()`, `WhereIsActive()`, and `ToList()`. If so you don't need to use mock objects.

Instead, I would write separate tests for each of those methods. This is the key to sane unit testing. The test for `FindAllActiveGamesFiles()` should avoid testing them if it can. You should only test the code inside `FindAllActiveGamesFiles()` if at all possible.

Next, the test for `FindAllActiveGamesFiles()` needs to set expectations for `mockRepository`. Assuming `Find()` and `WhereIsActive()` both return the same repository you will set the mock as the return value for those methods.

I don't know the API for your mocking library, but this is how it would look in psuedocode:

```
Mock<IRepository<GameFile>> mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<GameFile>>();
List<GameFile> result = new List<GameFile>();
mockRepository.expect('Find')->willReturn(mockRepository);
mockRepository.expect('WhereIsActive')->willReturn(mockRepository);
mockRepository.expect('ToList')->willReturn(result);
IGameFileService service = new GameFileService(mockRepository, fakeLoggingService);

assertSame(service.FindAllActiveGamesFiles(), result);
```

As you can see, the test code is more complicated than the code being tested. This is a good sign that you might not need the test.